# hair not rendering in blender and it is not showing up in object mode either

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, particles, hair

I have been having problems with the hair particle, for some reason the hair particles is now showing up as dots instead of hairs. I have no idea why it did this.

[image]

Can someone please help? I even tried to convert it to mesh which didn't work. I added the file as well so if anyone can show me what went wrong. File is too big to be uploaded through Blender Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the particle settings under render, you have selected object but haven't chosen an object to use. I expect you want to change that to path. Then under that in the display settings where you have chosen path, change that to rendered.

Comment: Thank you, I just saw this now. I redid the hair particles, but will keep this in mind for next time.